# How to call a child of a child that has a unique ID?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, multiplayer

I'm trying to make a multiplayer lobby using Firebase Realtime Database. I made it like `Rooms>UniqueID>UniqueID>player name` for the host.

I want the client to see a list of available rooms, with the name of the player who created it ("xxx's room'). They have unique ID's because I don't want to use an authentication service. The client can choose its name at the very beginning.

[image: image of rooms]

The problem is I can't read in the ref because of the unique ID which is a key :

```
let idr = firebase.database().ref().child('Rooms').push().key;
```

The host has the same ID as the room and other clients will have a unique one. This doesn't work :

```
var databaseRooms = firebase.database().ref('Rooms/');
var idrref = databaseRooms.child(idr/idr);
idrref.once('value',function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
        console.log(child.key+':'+child.val());
    });

    });
```

I tried copying the full id (`-Lfj5cS-1_jlfS7nf_Fb`) which works but it's a unique case so not what I want. Here is more code for better understanding :

```
let databaseRoom = firebase.database().ref('Rooms/');

function appuyerHost() {

    let pseudo = document.getElementById("inputpseudo").value;
    //Nom entrée par le joueur dans la barre "enter your name"
    let idr = firebase.database().ref().child('Rooms').push().key;
    //Créé un id spécial pour la room, meme si deux s'apelle pareille c ok  

    if (pseudo.length < 3) { 
        document.getElementById("alertpop").style.visibility = "visible"
        } else
    // Si le pseudo n'est pas de 3 caractères de long min. message d'erreur.

    var datar = {  
     user_name: pseudo
    }
     // Récupère l'id + le nom.

     let updatesr = {};
    updatesr['/Rooms/'+ idr +'/' + idr] = datar
    firebase.database().ref().update(updatesr);
    //envoie les données a la database, la room a l'id du joueur
}
```

Feel free to suggest different means of lobby creation. I'd appreciate an explanation of your understanding in addition to a solution.